# Как оптимально решить эту задачу на php?

Tags: php

Недавно решал тестовое задание на стажировку в одну контору. Не смог тогда в положенное время решить одну задачу, собственно пролетел. Потом решил её для себя, но у меня возник вопрос - достаточно ли моё решение оптимально, или, исходя из условий задачи, его можно как-то улучшить?
Вот сама задача:
[image: Описание задачи]

Вот моё окончательное решение (после строки комментария):

```
<?php
$cars = [
    ['name' => 'Такси 1', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
    ['name' => 'Такси 2', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
    ['name' => 'Такси 3', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
    ['name' => 'Такси 4', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
    ['name' => 'Такси 5', 'position' => rand(0, 1000), 'isFree' => (bool) rand(0, 1)],
];

$passenger = rand(0, 1000);

/* ===== Ваш код ниже ===== */

$min = null;
foreach($cars as $car){
    if($car['isFree']==true){
        if(abs($car['position'] - $passenger) < $min OR $min === null){
            $min = abs($car['position'] - $passenger);
     } 
 }
}

foreach($cars as $car){
    echo $car['name'].", стоит на ".$car['position']." км, до пассажира ".abs($car['position'] - $passenger)." км";
    if($car['isFree']==true){
        echo " (свободен)";
        if(abs($car['position'] - $passenger)==$min){
        echo " - едет эта машина";
        }
        echo "<br/>";
    } else{
        echo " (занят)"."<br/>";
    }   
}
?>
```

Я знаю, что эта задача здесь уже фигурировала, но тогда отвечающий при её решении использовал создание функции, а это запрещено условием. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Говоря об оптимальности надо указать __критерий оптимальности__.

Comment: а можно узнать парочку хотя бы, какие навскидку тут могли бы быть критерии? просто автор задачи не указал их явно

Comment: зачем вы пишите `$var == true` ? у вас слева от равно - булевое значение, формально вы сравниваете `true == true` или `false == true`.данные равенства это логические выражения, которое будет вычислено и вернет булевый результат.
А результат этот будет равен `true` только в случае, когда ваш аргумент истинный. Так так что не надо ничего сравнивать там, а просто использовать `if($var)`

Answer (score 0):

Безотносительно PHP, общечеловеческие замечания:

Зачем два (в итоге даже три) раза вычислять для каждой машины `abs($car['position'] - $passenger)`? Функция `min` поможет оформить сравнение более кратко. Если она вдруг запрещена - можно записать в переменную.

Что будет, если до двух машин одинаковое расстояние? Обе поедут?

При обновлении минимума нужно запоминать индекс, тогда вывод будет однозначен

Comment: Спасибо!) Но ведь в любом случае придётся сначала найти минимум в этом массиве, а потом уже выводить строку? Как-то совместить это не получится?

Comment: Нет смысла, т.к. другие машины тоже нужно выводить, а минимум будет известен только после проверки всех